# Battery information on Fluxbox

Tags: gnome, laptop, battery, fluxbox

How can I get my battery info (percentages) on Fluxbox?

I've heard of the `gnome-power-manager`, and wanted to use that, but there seems to be a problem...

```
$ gnome-power-manager
gnome-power-manager: command not found
```

And when I try to install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-power-manager 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-power-manager is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 141 not upgraded.
```

I reinstalled it, and still the same situation! Apparently it's installed, but Ubuntu doesn't recognize the command. Also, I don't really like `wmbattery`, I'd like something that exists next to those applets and other icons (nm-applet, sound, Skype, etc).

I have highlighted the area I would like to have the battery information applet at:

[image]

Comment: fluxbox isnt a common WM - so it might help if you can add a picture as to your current desktop - where such an applet would exist, how have you installed other fluxbox applets.

Comment: Other applets I already had. For example, simply putting `nm-applet &` in the `.fluxbox/startup` file gets me that network applet.

Comment: I would recommend adding gnome-power-manager into your fluxbox startup and see what happens, some forums I have read seem to suggest that works. Otherwise have you tried xfce4-power-manager?

Comment: I haven't tried xfce4, but adding gnome-power-manager does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After researching this myself recently I settled on **batti**.

Batti is:

- a very lightweight gtk app written in Python
- easily installable from source
- shows detailed battery information including time remaining when you hover over the indicator
- Allows you to suspend/power off by selecting from the menu after a left click.

It's available [from here](http://code.google.com/p/batti-gtk/).

Once downloaded and unpacked, simply call

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Add `batti` to your autostart menu to have it load when you login - in your case just add it to your `.fluxbox/startup` file.

Some screenshots of batti in action (it's the battery icon, not the lightning symbol - that's jupiter power management applet):

[image: Definitely half empty ;)]
[image: Some useful info]

Comment: Great, it works!

Comment: Excellent solution. Just commenting to report that this work perfect in i3WM. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I use the xfce4-power-manager

http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/xfce4-power-manager

Comment: xfce power manager was not so nice for me: It promissed to suspend my netbook when I closed the lid, and failed to (which is annoying and a bit dangerous...)